# Parse Name in A string

Tags: c#, regex

How to use regex to match this in C#?

```
1.1 or 2.1 or 1.I/3 or 1.C/1
```

That mean the string begin with a number, followed by a dot (.) , then followed by a number or a character C, I (or any letter A - Z), then followed by a splash(/), then a number

I have tried this expression, but it doesn't work.

```
string patternName = @"\d\.(\d|I/\d|C/\d)";
```

Comment: we are trying to edit your post and correct spelling and grammar errors so people can understand your question better.

Comment: thank you, sorry for my expresion in English.

Comment: Is the slash used only after a character, or is something like 1.2/1 valid as well?

Comment: Should the pattern only match single digits before the dot, or would 12.1 and 12.I/2 be valid? What about 1.10?

Comment: yes, the slash used only after a character

Comment: @chungphamnhu - when you say any character, do you mean any character, including non-alpha characters, or only alpha characters (i.e., letters a through z)?

Comment: @Jason Aller: pattern can match one or many digits before the dot

Comment: @Tim: sorry, only A-Z character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. Try this:

```
string patternName = @"\d\.(?:\d|[A-Z]/\d)";
```

Or more simply

```
string patternName = @"\d\.(?:[A-Z]/)?\d";
```

If you want to allow more than one digit (e.g. `1.10` or `2.I/22`), use a one-or-more (`+`) qunatifier:

```
string patternName = @"\d+\.(?:[A-Z]/)?\d+";
```

For example:

```
string input = "1.1NGUYEN/VAN DUONG MR 2.1NGUYEN/THI ANH MRS 3.I/1NGUYEN/THI NHU QUYNH";
string patternName = @"\d+\.(?:[A-Z]/)?\d+";
string[] output = Regex.Split(input, patternName);
// [ "", "NGUYEN/VAN DUONG MR ", "NGUYEN/THI ANH MRS ", "NGUYEN/THI NHU QUYNH" ]
```

Comment: Change the second one to `@"\d+\.([A-Z]/)?\d+`" and I think we have a winner.

Comment: than you p.s.w.g but when i try tring patternName = @"\d+\.(./)?\d+" the result not exact, for example:
 1.1NGUYEN/VAN DUONG MR  2.1NGUYEN/THI ANH MRS  3.I/1NGUYEN/THI NHU QUYNH 

After split Names
 
NGUYEN/VAN DUONG MR  
NGUYEN/THI ANH MRS  
I/
NGUYEN/THI NHU QUYNH

Comment: @chungphamnhu Can you clarify what exactly you expect it to be? If you're using `Split` you probably need to use a non-capturing group. See my updated answer.

Comment: I expect that: NGUYEN/VAN DUONG MR  
NGUYEN/THI ANH MRS  
NGUYEN/THI NHU QUYNH , not incule /I as a part

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
(\d+\.(?:\d+|C|I)(?:\/\d+)?)
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rG7gI8)**

**EXPLANATION**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern (updated):

```
\d\.[\dIC]\/?\d?
```

Comment: `\d.[\dIC]\/?\d?` will match anything in the second position, including the dot - i.e., "19" will match `\d.`.  I think you mean `\d\.`.